# Select delete and insert at the same time PHP and SQL Server

Tags: php

What I want to do is first Select if the Cardindex Column has the values 0.1 and 2. with the same UserIndex (id) if those values exist (The 3 are mandatory), then we proceed to delete the 3 themselves and then Insert in the same table a new value. as long as the previous condition is met, if it is not met, it is not inserted.

In the query that I show the first query works well, it removes the data 0,1,2, until there everything is perfect, but then when inserting the new row it does it, but without respecting the previous condition. if in case it was not fulfilled it inserts it anyway.

It seems very easy but it has been impossible for me to continue moving forward,
Sorry for my bad English

[Imagen Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLLQV.png)

```
include('Login/Conexion.php');
$id = $_SESSION['id'];

$query = "with cte as (SELECT count(*) over() cnt FROM CardData where UserIndex = $id and CardIndex in (0, 1, 2)) delete from cte where cnt = 3";
$resultados = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);

if($resultados){
    $insert = sqlsrv_query($conn,"INSERT INTO CardData (UserIndex, CardIndex, Mode ) VALUES ('$id', '5' ,'1')");
    }
    else{
        echo 'Error';
        }
```

Comment: According to the php docs, the `sqlsrv_query` function returns a statement resource, not a true/false whether the statement did anything.

Comment: @JakeParis I use if(f$resultados ==true) it does not work

Answer (score 0):

`sqlsrv_query()` only returns `FALSE` if there was an error. Your logic is assuming that if the first query has no matches, `$resultados` will be false, but that's not correct.

You could try checking the number of affected rows instead:

```
$query = "with cte as (SELECT count(*) over() cnt FROM CardData where UserIndex = $id and CardIndex in (0, 1, 2)) delete from cte where cnt = 3";
$resultados = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);

if( sqlsrv_num_fields($resultados) ) {
    $insert = sqlsrv_query($conn,"INSERT INTO CardData (UserIndex, CardIndex, Mode ) VALUES ('$id', '5' ,'1')");
    }
else {
   echo 'Error';
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_get_fields() in..

Comment: My fault, it's `sqlsrv_num_fields`,

Comment: if( sqlsrv_num_fields($resultados) Select and delete correctly but now  it doesn't insert the new row, always shows me echo 'error' :(

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
if($fila = sqlsrv_rows_affected($resultados)) { 
 $insert = sqlsrv_query($conn,"INSERT INTO CardData (UserIndex, CardIndex, Mode ) VALUES ('$id', '5' ,'1')");
}
else {
echo 'Error';
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.